# Click,trigger animation and play sound.Going from keydown to click

Tags: javascript, html

Following this drumkit tutorial but wanted to change it to where I could click instead of pressing key(in this example pressing A triggers the animation and sound). Tried changing the 'keydown' in the window.addEventListener to 'click' but nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?

Extra details if needed.There are two functions. The first one plays the corresponding audio tag that matches the keycode of the data-key div.
The second function just returns the transformation in the css back to its original state.

```js
function playSound(e) {

  const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return; //stop the function from running all together
  audio.currentTime = 0; // rewind to the start
  audio.play();
  key.classList.add('playing');


}


function removeTransition(e) {

  if (e.propertyName !== 'transform') return; // skip it if its not a transform

  this.classList.remove('playing');

}


const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));

window.addEventListener('keydown', playSound);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

html {
  font-size: 10px;
  /*background: url(http://i.imgur.com/b9r5sEL.jpg) bottom center;*/
  /* background-size: cover;*/
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.keys {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.key {
  border: .4rem solid mistyrose;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem .5rem;
  transition: all .07s ease;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(245, 245, 220, 0.4);
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5rem black;
}

.playing {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem black;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="soundpad.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">      
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="65" src="clap.wav"></audio>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you've got lays down under wrong propperty you are trying to use to get data from.
*keyCode* attribute can be used when you pressing buttons on keyboard but your goal is to get it from *data-key* attribute. 
So first you have to change:

```
e.keyCode
```

To

```
e.target.dataset.key
```

Like this:

```
const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${e.target.dataset.key}"]`);
const key = document.querySelector(`.key[data-key="${e.target.dataset.key}"]`);
```

Plus you need to add listener of click not on window object, but on certain html element. For example could be used same *forEach* loop

```
keys.forEach((key) => {
    key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition);
    key.addEventListener('click', playSound);
});
```